# Alternative to "come into clash"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase-request

Is it possible to say: "Some Wikipedia information came into clash with the law." to imply there's been a legal case against some information published?

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what you want to say. You have not used an idiomatic phrase. "Clash with" is idiomatic as is "come into conflict with."

However, the idea that information can conflict with law makes no sense given normal meanings of those words in English. The law, at least for many centuries now, targets persons (natural or artificial), not things without volition.

What you may be trying to say is:

"Wikipedia's possession of that information is illegal" or

"Wikipedia's publication of that information is illegal."

Notice the distinction. In actual fact, I legally have in my possession information that US federal law prohibits me from making public. It is a legal duty for me to know that information; it is a crime for me to make it known to others. But the law applies to me as a person; the law does not attempt to admonish the information itself.

Comment: +1 for "that information can conflict with law makes no sense given normal meanings of those words in English"

Answer (score 1):

"Some Wikipedia information came into clash with the law." is not semantically or grammatically correct.

Some of the information on Wikipedia is not in keeping with the law.

Some of the information on Wikipedia contravenes the law or violates the law.

Note: one wonders which law......but

Comment: In modern Anglo-American law, information is neither legal nor illegal. It can't be. With very odd exceptions, only individuals or organizations presumed capable of knowledgeable volition are subject to law. What may be illegal is posession or publication of particular types of information by certain parties, e.g. medical records.

Comment: Well, Wikipedia is a party. Remember the Supreme Court decision? Companies are people. Anyway, we don't know exactly that the OP is saying.The information on Wikipedia may contravene EU privacy laws, for all I know or China...who knows?

Comment: Sorry. I am being persnickety. Wikipedia can easily contravene the law in any number of jurisdictions. At least under Anglo-American law, information cannot.

Comment: Yes, Jeff, but just because something is not true does not mean that an OP doesn't want to say that, right? I mean one thing is grammar, another is truth, knowledge and logic, right? I essentially agree with you, of course.

Comment: Indeed, Lambie. It is perfectly true that nonsense and error can be expressed grammatically. It is my delusion, however, that clear language reduces the liklihood of nonsense and error. I keep trying.

Comment: @JeffMorrow I'm with you there. :)